# Check function uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-continuity

The task is to check function uniform continuity in terms of the following set $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \geq 2\}$:
$$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

Can you help me with this one?
I have been solving with only single point to check, however here is the whole set, have no idea what to do with that.

Comment: Hint: $t \sin (\frac 1 t) \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, yes, but I don't understand here how to operate with the set of values instead of one point, that is my main problem..

Comment: If a continuous function $f(x)$ has a finite limit as $\|x\| \to \infty$ then it is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering new variable $z = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ we have composition of continuous function with uniformly continuous $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ on $0 \leqslant z \leqslant 1$.

Comment: And isn't $f(x,y)$ continious out of that interval $z \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Your question stated $z \in (0,1]$. Outside it's again continuous and have limit in $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Got it